# Is there any good strategy for manhunt in Assassin's Creed Brotherhood?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

There are some tips that the system show in Assassin's Creed Brotherhood for the manhunt on-line mode. However I would like to know if there are any kind of strategy you could use to get more points in the game.

Is there any way to avoid being flanked by your pursuers during manhunt? I am always caught by pursuers who flanked me.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is stick with your team.  Unfortunately this game type (and just about any other team game type) is seriously broken -- Ever get stuck in a stun chain when the whole defending team has smokes and other incapacitation abilities to just lock the rest of the pursuing team by stunning them constantly for the whole match?

Comment: Yes it happened before but I found the solution to it. When you get stunned press triangle (on the ps3 version) then select another skill set profile, then you will respawn at a different place where you can counter or at least run from the defending team.

Comment: Yeah, it just sucks that you have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

### Some Strategies!

I got this list of some cool strategies to use when playing Manhunt :

> **Packing Hunt** 
>   The team works alongside each other while seeking and killing the opposing team. This usually includes communication through headsets or simple instinctive ganging-up on a tough defender.
>   If all four players on defense stick together, the best choice is for all the hunters to stick together and hunt as a group as well; the key is waiting for everybody to be in position and coordinating attacks to avoid being caught in a stun trap.
>
> **Safety in Numbers** 
>   The defenders all stay in a large group, or in smaller groups close to each other. When an enemy has been spotted, every defender will focus on stunning them or disabling them in order to gain points or help their teammates escape.
>
> **Stun Traps**
>   Also referred to as "Stun Locking". This usually works best with a group of two or three defenders. When an attacker has been spotted and comes close, one of the defenders can either get a stun or throw a Smoke Bomb and stun the pursuer. While the pursuer is on the ground, a different defender can wait by them and stun the pursuer again without the use of any abilities.
>   A pursuer can be stunned several times in a row by defenders that alternate their stuns. This is repeated until the attacker gives up and respawns (by pressing the Triangle or Y button) or if the attacker's teammates arrive to help their comrade. Another effective technique should you choose not to respawn or your teammates are unable to help you is to have the perk Resistance. Resistance allows you to get up quicker after being stunned and therefore interrupt the rhythm of a stun lock. However, in doing this you risk not getting your contract quick enough and therefore being stunned again.

Answer (score -2):

Watch that, it's includes all suggestions for you.

Comment: Could you explain the video a bit in case people can't access Youtube? Thanks.